# Decode response from the server which based on (HttpWebResponse)

Tags: c#, webrequest, httpwebresponse

I have some problem with decoding the answer using the `HttpWebrequest`. When i authenticated in the server, i want to get the html code of the page. But get the:

> ‹?????­YлrЫЖ~h“Ж@D‚¤-ЫAKkQ¶2–м±h;©ДhVА‚ШPм‚”МСLях:У·hчOЯ&УѕFПо .”­(хLн№|зІзњ] ы[o_N~z761‡ыщ/%ЮpNІHєфП[`ф2ЋЌDwr“Pdёz…‘ Чў'7 )§gВпоў^‘9Е(Ґ‘GSљV—фтЉ‰R®jкЗо‡Qчe<O€`—aХЪСSoFиF—IњЉЉ ‹`$мr—„м~'г4UKђ8Љ~њО‰иzTPW°8Є…Т$€#©ХЎsВBщсRКyHtN»nЖХhїйчww]WК†,є2R‚“®ґ¤Фыd!—6ь C@ЋЃ='3Ъ»о*1PL„tш‰u™с‰^§4]Рtї§йWѓqqRЫеiCjНJUѕ№›ІD<uЃЈю¶б…QµџїђС4Ьпйїкz—ЏwЈЯ¤u‡њџE*Э†ЬГГ,OЭ”ТИф¬Х‚¤ЕћнЕn6‡$ЋC*уMj§P*”©Б•†µЪ@4-з–†њJgОЯoТЪ@nиЕџ+§kЕ
>   фє¦®сЌКw°¤юm™—D.
>   лi`П¦Ч¬E“RuГѓЗ-щ&­Ў~Щ°­”ЪдєћЋj“кfN=\Ж[Ўў‡П"кЎ-,k(ц
>   йьЪсј,¬•_’рF    зцN<я+hюoА‚U#Ї{Uе}C'л€Я   Фpneїш›kAл…10цЊѕ“R‘ҐpµTs…г3Ddu`Zъ1<–Мgрр™Б#Ње/сж,‚g–фІd–ЏВb–1х$    љ:лjХГо"Њ‰gІўЃ•±36uаlpгшЉQIк°Ћ1иГ?ЛщЦD…ІџВE–-§ЭF¶<Zђі®@№€ИВФр>†ЬyJJ    тйoa„4/d0KЂtz'±G№УЮ”2М`‘ґVрc3Aзаён†„у5НQћ1†
>   Жих[0c9ҐBRS аж‚"ТeJ"мІ(ўйлЙс|‘‡ѕќXаBи©@ЄА—LёБG… Yп‡|Z–сbГ`(ё{­IZp*IњQ±” aK)^j?1OЦ*Ї–З№5КNПA›Г2БаQєЏ°s›Л†џAЫПЧ”Н±СQНєї§
>   Ё{I—ѕ>лч+О’LДp%`џi^њБз8w?язжћЋ«0o}MрOBrѓуў>ЫйC…ЎЛ0vЇЊЏG}9*"т–€,MЕБІёvмыРќЪTwРW<ҐРиmЗН-JЫ(№®цx–x.]$љ™1l>\е&РJФэ1‚¦°І)&pЏ;€б*™H{-еЧыЦ‘:z'ьўД•?kD;ХBQkђGr’чќ_±ј…ЛУОГ»]т#йЌoWьсеХ}µЄМ[(Џ<S*кЇf=ЩfФТЩ_Ы\џ{е$—s*пў}и"лKЭ†dWU‹^ДіYH5И!+є3­ХбµP1KVчqEџtq/3¬ЫWБ^ҐђЂbMpD—ЖДЫґѕёE‹Бж№ч}ёЙzЦК
>   )I‹Ґ№f8UмВMёБ6©Љz‚ИЭ>ҐPF7a5[Ї¬нЃе\LL$eQ‡кµОD7рЇ{|Ьх<#цжу=x7ЄµsІ0Їѓґw ‘№
>   ћЏ~эxqxtrtъz|­кЩ!Tа­ѓ'ІЋdЪђQж:Р]ЪQyя0щv!›д¬?µ:•е`juUВг©UЁїЋі”йЙґ і(TТvJZ?9{:­&Xeж+YмT_WR\ж]ѕ•G№wаМЙЅИЯЇ`BИ9j'AЃѕ{{:Ѓ‡А!К»юц6пш8’WA\ZЙ'Ґ,DЬљ­ІйG
>   ЅЪ]т№UHЌ.Еуѕј{В)ЋВ,QЙ*ї:ШZЁќЦњS.Д›O"‚гв$’ођіёy©щRМaЊ†Љk’Ћў;
>   -МахЎq0J_Кі±zq*mе”{Ј№x-и¬*Ъ{ъ#РeмЭч=¶0‡+зѕЎ.ј
>   Mб•?tхEµ>U‹ЃЭмЃЖ,…!ЛГ}’»XШ[Џd`КЏ\Ў'  р рАХ0µOjЪA°ГтхDіЂvIТ®·Еч-‚а<Ђы’{6тi\ШН•е§.ЁЇНяnO›Э{бЂѓЋлыJ%ac>¤Ђ¬ЙE-куqуqСЅїЗЧ'mЬ'hx2ћGЈWГЬicо@!|џLЊ7oъґ
>   ъ
>   GЗG'|Ц|††ЮЅz?:?тyт9lТСџFп†ёЫFЬ…Ё]К№с.f‘hБцІpc;ЙуІЮO№%АgкUІх›юЅјA\КЇБ
>   еИИ*у•’ёЊSмхеDQЧ‹jЂеЧ!9µеr
>   иГLэїЉбя?бДЩЕъ??

Please help me to solve my problem< there is my code:

```
           public static void RequestMutualAuths()
        {
            string logon = "admin";
            string password = "admin";
            string url = "http://192.168.1.55/";
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(logon + ":" + password));
            request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("Basic {0}", credentials);
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "text/plain");
                Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
                using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251")))
                    {
                        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

                        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: why are you specifying windows-1251 encoding when reading data?

Comment: I try, "utf-8" char-set, but its not working too. I have similar answer in response.

Comment: `request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");` Is it, by any chance, compressed? If it is, see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.automaticdecompression.aspx).

Comment: If I remove this options I get one-by-one result

Comment: @Serhii what do you mean?

Comment: It option not metter, I get this option in server network settings.

Comment: Correct my request for it to work

Comment: Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
class IrequesttoKness
{
    public static void LoadHttpPageWithBasicAuthentication(string login, string password, RestClient url)
    {
        var client = url;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(login + ":" + password));
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic" + credentials);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var html = response.Content;
        Console.WriteLine(html);
    }
}
```